# Длительный фоновый процесс в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

У меня есть `web api` на `asp.net core`. По кнопке с формы запускаю фоновую задачу, которая может выполняться до 5 часов.

Проблема такая, что по истечению около 1 часа фоновая задача принудительно завершается.

Сначала фоновую задачу запускал таким способом:

```
// POST api/analytics/run
[Route("api/[controller]/run")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> RunAnalyticsAsync([FromBody] DataRequested dataRequested)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        do
        {
            //
        }
        while (report.Status == ReportStatus.Working);
        await CloudTableService.UpdateClientData(report);
    });
}
```

Как видно из кода данные должны сохраняться в таблицу. Если фоновый поток работает меньше часа, то так и происходит. Если больше, то до сохранения не доходит.
Сначала, я подумал, что некорректно запускаю фоновый процесс.

Нашел статью [Фоновые задачи с размещенными службами в ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks)

Выбрал последний вариант: **Фоновые задачи в очереди**. Адаптировал под свой проект. Запускаю в режиме отладки **F5**. И где-то через час происходит тоже самое. Еще заметил, что в режиме отладки в `visual studio` по истечению часа, она(отладка) завершается(окна Вывод, стек вызовов закрывается), информации об исключениях или ошибках нет никакой, `web api` по-прежнему доступно. При обновлении страницы в веб-приложении(которое работает с `web api`) информация об активной фоновой задаче пропадает и подгружаются из таблицы результаты предыдущей фоновой задачи.

Активные задачи сохраняю вот в таком классе, который объявлен как синглтон сервис.

```
public class MemoryCacheService : IMemoryCacheService
{
    public IList<BaseReportRealTime> RealTimeReports { get; }

    public MemoryCacheService()
    {
        RealTimeReports = new List<BaseReportRealTime>();
    }
}

public interface IMemoryCacheService
{
    IList<BaseReportRealTime> RealTimeReports { get; }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Как вы хостите ваш вебсервер? Например, IIS может убивать процесс, если сайт долго не используется - это надо в пуле приложения настраивать. Если же вы просто dotnet run используете, то тогда вам надо все, что у вас происходит в коде, логгировать, так как у меня обычный dotnet run может нежелями висеть и ничего не убивать.

Comment: @tym32167, да использую IIS. И еще возник вопрос тогда: если IIS убивает процесс, тогда asp-net core web api тоже не будет доступно?

Comment: процесс помирает для всех вебсайтов (для всего, что хостится на IIS), так как это то, как работает пул приложений. Это дело можно исправить в настйроках пула приложений, я точно настройку не помню, но вам ниже уже подсказывают куда копать. Правите настройки пула и ваш процесс будет работать без перерывов

Comment: На такие долгие задачи я все таки посоветовал бы запускать как standalone приложение, и уже на него проксировать трафик.

Comment: @ГеннадийП спасибо. Учту на будущее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверьте `Idle Timeout` в настройках Application Pool вашего сервиса.
Cкорее всего процесс сбрасывается самим IIS'ом

Comment: Спасибо, попробую